# basic_ostringstream::str dangling pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

Recently I found the bug in the following code:

```
ostringstream o;
o << "some string";
const char* s = o.str().c_str(); // empty string instead of expected "some string"
```

This is explained by cppreference.com: **the copy of the underlying string returned by str is a temporary object that will be destructed at the end of the expression, so directly calling c_str() on the result of str() (for example in auto *ptr = out.str().c_str();) results in a dangling pointer.**

I don't have any problem fixing this bug, however, I have many places in the projects, which look like this:

```
ostringstream o;
o << "error description";
throw my_exception(o.str().c_str());

...

my_exception::my_exception(const char* s) :
    message(s)     // message is std::string
{}
```

Does this code has undefined behavior, like the first code fragment?

Comment: While you're at it, you could still refactor that code. If you just derived from `std::runtime_error` (instead of reimplementing its functionality), you could simply pass it a `std::string`, removing a bunch of code and maybe even avoiding a copy on the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, message(s) is a std::string so you take a copy of the contents of the char buffer at that point.

The temporary lasts for the scope of the function you call it with - in this case the constructor.

Comment: The temporary lasts until the end of throw expression (so that includes the `my_exception` constructor).

Comment: But it is dodgy.  If my_exception was changed to store the const char * you would be back to your original problem.  A better solution is to give my_exception a constructor which takes a `const std::string&` or even a `const ostringstream&`, and construct message directly from that.

Comment: It's particularly wierd to convert a std::string to char *, and then promptly change it back.

Comment: @Jarod42: can you give me some confirmation (probably from C++ specification) of this"the temporary lasts until the end of throw expression"? It is the most important point for me. Thanks.

Comment: @0123456789: as you quote *"will be destructed at the end of the expression"* and it is used into `throw my_exception(o.str().c_str())` a throw expression. That doesn't change the behavior in your case (as *in constructor* is enough).

Comment: Temporaries wouldn't be very useful otherwise.